# Javascript doesnt work after paste seach form to <head> tag

Tags: javascript, html

i need help with javascript problem, i want to insert a search form to my website navigation, but after i paste searchform html code , all my javascript not working, example - Audio Play container "javascript" doesnt working. maybe i cannot place html before /head tag?

Update :

after adding closing tag , my searchbox is working!

Comment: Are you missing a closing tag for your form ?

Comment: Where did you paste this - i.e. what file, and (if applicable) what function?
Can you include the code surrounding this?

Comment: you cannot insert `view` elements inside the `<head>` tag

Comment: All the rendered content of a page goes in `<body>`. `<head>` is for metadata and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no, you can not place HTML elements in the `<head>` tag. These things must go between the opening `<body>` tag and before the closing `</body>` tag.

Additionally, you're not closing your form, the following example would be a 'complete' form in your case:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" _lpchecked="1">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="<?php _e('Search the site','point'); ?>" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _e('Search the site','point'); ?>';}" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e('Search the site','point'); ?>') {this.value = '';}" >
        <button id="search-image" class="sbutton" type="submit" value="">
            <i class="point-icon icon-search"></i>
        </button>
        <!-- <input id="search-image" class="sbutton" type="submit" style="border:0; vertical-align: top;" value="<?php //_e('Search','point'); ?>"> -->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

You'll notice I've added a `</form>` tag after your `</fieldset>`.

Comment: thanks that worked, but i have different problem occurred.